# Point nameservers away from AWS to standard host

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, nameservers

Do I just have to change the A NAME records, or do I also have to change the nameservers and C NAME fields?

Answer (score 1):

You mainly need to change the name server entries and use the name servers of the standard hosts. once you change the name severs to standard host, the `A` records and `CName` records defined in AWS become useless. To keep things clean, you can deleted the entries or hosted zones in Route53.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It’s running a load balancer, and some redirects, do I need to disable these first?

Comment: I don't think so, but better to remove the dns entries and make a note of these , especially if you are planning to keep these load balancers

Comment: It’s not a registered domain, it’s a hosted zone, should that matter?

Comment: If you are moving the dns management outside of route53, the hostedzones becomes useless. You can remove it.

Comment: Brilliant. Do I ‘have’ to remove the zone for the repoint to work? I changed the nameservers (and A records) a few hours ago and it just broke the site. I didn’t remove anything else.

Comment: If you are repointing the load balancer, you have to created a cname instead of A record when you point from non route53 DNS management service

Comment: Also don't forget, DNS propogation may take time to propogate all around the World

Comment: I really just want to move completely away from AWS as I’m out of my depth.

Comment: Ok  Post a exact problem you are facing. There are plenty of us to help

Comment: Ok. In a new post yeah? Thanks again

Comment: Yes. Try to give much details as possible. If your problem has nothing to do with code, you can post in other stack exchange network sites

Answer (score 0):

you can simply update name server provided by your standard host a record and other records will be updated accordingly.